# CSS - Making all images have a circular type border

Tags: css

In my project, I allow users to upload profile pictures. I want these pictures to have a  circular border, like instagram profile pictures do. Does anybody know how to add this affect?

I have tried the `border-radius` property, however this makes some images with white/transparent backgrounds looking like they have been cropped, and doesn't have the expected outcome.

Does anybody know how to add a circular type border to any image that is upload by a user? Thank you.

**HTML CODE:**

```
.fixedImage {
    position: relative;
    left: 70px;
    width: 25px;
    top: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Please share an example and some code please.

Comment: @Christian Please check original post update. This is the code I have so far, however images with transparent backgrounds get cut, and give a cropped look to it. Other images are fine. Do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: add your own background to make sure there is no transparent part

Comment: @TemaniAfif What do you mean by this? I don't understand can you write an answer that demonstrates this? An example of what the code would look like.

Comment: I mean: `background:#fff` to the image for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a border and a box-shadow...

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2em 3em;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  background: lightgreen;
}

img {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px red;
}

.white {
  border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Transparent border
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/150/150" alt="">
</div>

<div>
  White border
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/150/150" alt="" class="white">
</div>
```

Comment: One thing I do not understand is what this `box-shadow` property does in this instance. Can you help me out?

Comment: Could you please explain what the `box-shadow` property actually does in this **particular** instance? Thank you.

Comment: Nice answer! The box shadow adds a red border where the real `border` is transparent in one example and white in the other example.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `img`, you can use `div` and have your image in background. This will allow you to add a background color of your choice to avoid the transparency.

Example:

```
<div class="fixedImage" style="background-image: url(img.png)"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.fixedImage {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 70px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;                                
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-size: 100px 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think https://medium.com/@biancapower/how-to-make-a-rectangle-image-a-circle-in-css-2f392bc9abd3 is what you are looking for.

A div around the image gets the `border-radius: 50%`

HTML:

```
 <div class="image-cropper">
   <img src="https://www4.lunapic.com/editor/premade/transparent.gif">
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.image-cropper {
  width: 240px; // it seems you need to add the padding twice here
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bdL8zmu1/

Without background color:

https://jsfiddle.net/94z27bdL/

Comment: Well some images with a transparent background get cropped because of this property. Do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: The HTML, CSS and JS code windows are all empty. No code inside. Could you try to add all the code in that jsfiddle into an answer? Thank you.

Comment: Yes this is closer to what I want. The only problem I have is that since the **user** will be uploading their own pictures, some pics I tested did not fit the circle properly. Bits were popping out, and the image was unpositioned.

Comment: Do you know how to make it so **all** images are adjusted so it fits the circle properly. Maybe position it, center it or crop the image?

Comment: It all boils down to `border-radius: 50%`. The images in the other answer have exactly a width and height of 150px, this is maybe not the case when users can upload images, you can either stretch or crop them during upload, or allow only one size for upload.